# php foreach loop duplicate items

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am getting data from my database. everything works but the foreach loop gets duplicate items. I am getting the team names as duplicates.

Picture:[image]

I know it's the fault of this code because it's inside a foreach loop but i don't know how to fix this:

```
foreach($arrayTotals as $team=>$values){
        foreach($values as $v){
            echo "<tr class=\"" . $v['kaupunki_id'] . "\"><td>".$numerointi .".";
            echo "<td>" . $team;
            $sum1=0;
            $sum2=0;
            $numerointi ++;
        }
```

My whole code:

```
$arrayTotals = array();
    foreach ($db->query("SELECT pisteet_1, pisteet_2, nimi, team_id, pisteet.kaupunki_id FROM pisteet INNER JOIN joukkueet ON joukkueet.id=pisteet.team_id ORDER BY team_id ASC") as $joukkuenimi) {

         $arrayTotals[$joukkuenimi['nimi']][] = array('pisteet_1'=>$joukkuenimi['pisteet_1'],'pisteet_2'=>$joukkuenimi['pisteet_2'],'kaupunki_id'=>$joukkuenimi['kaupunki_id']);

    }
//var_dump($arrayTotals);
$numerointi =1;
echo "<table class=\"zebra\">";
foreach($arrayTotals as $team=>$values){
    foreach($values as $v){
        echo "<tr class=\"" . $v['kaupunki_id'] . "\"><td>".$numerointi .".";
        echo "<td>" . $team;
        $sum1=0;
        $sum2=0;
        $numerointi ++;
    }
    foreach($values as $v){
            echo "<td class=\"pisteet\">" . $v['pisteet_1'] . "/" . $v['pisteet_2'] . "</td>";
            $sum1 +=$v['pisteet_1'];
            $sum2 +=$v['pisteet_2'];
    }
    echo '<td class="summa">'.$sum1.'/'.$sum2."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

My array if i enable:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayTotals);

Array
(
    [Itis/hki] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pisteet_1] => 6
                    [pisteet_2] => 10
                    [kaupunki_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pisteet_1] => 3
                    [pisteet_2] => 10
                    [kaupunki_id] => 1
                )

        )

    [Harju/Jyväskylä] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pisteet_1] => 3
                    [pisteet_2] => 10
                    [kaupunki_id] => 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pisteet_1] => 4
                    [pisteet_2] => 10
                    [kaupunki_id] => 5
                )

        )

    [Jojot] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pisteet_1] => 6
                    [pisteet_2] => 10
                    [kaupunki_id] => 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pisteet_1] => 7
                    [pisteet_2] => 10
                    [kaupunki_id] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Tried replacing `inner join` by `left join`? Without having any example data or the schemas it's not possible to help.

Comment: You have commented out `//var_dump($arrayTotals);`. What does `var_dump($arrayTotals);` give you?

Comment: @Sean I included the array result.

Comment: but they all are different.

Comment: @suchit yes but the foreach loop adds the name two times. but i don't know how to format my loops that it would work. Sorry if my question was a little unclear.

Comment: what exactly you want in your result. sum of row data or individual column data.

Comment: The name (nimi) the points (pisteet_1, pisteet_2) and the city id (kaupunki_id). and the total points each team has. at the moment the code is doing this but it adds the name two times (itis/hki, Harju/Jyväskylä, jojot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `foreach()` is causing the issue, as it is looping through both subarrays before printing the second foreach loop. Try removing it, and just reference the first `$v['kaupunki_id']` using `$values[0]['kaupunki_id']` -

```
$numerointi =1;
echo "<table class=\"zebra\">";
foreach($arrayTotals as $team=>$values){
    echo "<tr class=\"" . $values[0]['kaupunki_id'] . "\"><td>".$numerointi .".";
    echo "<td>" . $team;
    $sum1=0;
    $sum2=0;
    $numerointi ++;

    foreach($values as $v){
            echo "<td class=\"pisteet\">" . $v['pisteet_1'] . "/" . $v['pisteet_2'] . "</td>";
            $sum1 +=$v['pisteet_1'];
            $sum2 +=$v['pisteet_2'];
    }
    echo '<td class="summa">'.$sum1.'/'.$sum2."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
$db->query("SELECT pisteet_1, pisteet_2, nimi, team_id, pisteet.kaupunki_id FROM pisteet INNER JOIN joukkueet ON joukkueet.id=pisteet.team_id where pisteet_1 is not null or pisteet_1 !='' ORDER BY team_id ASC")
```

Note: in where clause you can add your desired condition which you thind will de good to get the appropriate result or add more than one condition which should be true to get the result.
this will ommite the result with blank or null values.

Comment: i am still getting the same result :/

Comment: it will be better if you add the column names at the top of your question by editing. and use distinct with select and see.

Answer (score 0):

Try if the code below will help you to remove duplicates.

```
function find_dup($p1, $p2){
   $n=0;
foreach($p1 as $key => $val){
if($val==$p2) $n++;
return $nb;
}

$ar = array(10,20,10,30,40,10);
echo find_dup($ar,10) // will output 3
```